# Cloud Function is running faster than I need it to

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-platform

**Background**

I am creating a cloud function to import a csv into a AutoML dataset.

**Issue**

My issue, is that my function runs too quick and it won't process information until the first one uploaded is done. How could I 'slow down' my program(not talking about changing the max invocations) inside of the code.

**Idea for Solution**

Is it possible to add a timer that will not not let you skip the line of code until the counter is complete?

Comment: Why it's too quick? What's your error?

Comment: provide code, please

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar too much with GCP but there are basic concepts that should be available to you.

When you upload the CSV file it's an asynchronous action, therefore you can [async-await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) until the loading is finished and then trigger uploading the data to AutoML.

If that is not the issue you could provide some code snippet to better understand the problem you are facing.